# How to set ListPreference defaultValue in xml based on OS version

Tags: android, android-xml

I'm providing a ListPreference that has a different set of entryValues and entries based on the version of Android on the device. That's easy: the same string-array is defined in values/res.xml then overridden in values-v29/res.xml.

But I want the defaultValue on v29 and above to be a string that's only available on v29 and above. (The default for older versions is available on all; it's just not the default on newer devices.) How do I specify a defaultValue in a way that can be overridden by a resource in an .xml file in values-v29/? I basically need to add a level of indirection, but can't figure out how Android supports that.

I know I can set the default programmatically based on Build.VERSION.SDK_INT, but that's gross. Much better to keep everything in xml if possible.

Thanks,

--Eric House

Comment: Is the same approach you've used for the array not working for `defaultValue`? I mean, can't you define separate `<string>`s for the `defaultValue` in each of those folders, too?

Comment: I can make it work that way, but it's ugly, and doesn't really solve
the problem of keeping things in XML. If I define the same string
differently in values-v29 then the code that's responding to the
setting needs to behave differently (based on the OS version) when the
setting is the default.

And localization would be a mess, as translators would need to provide
different translations for different OS versions.

Comment: There's no code: `android:defaultValue="@string/versioned_default_value"`.

Comment: So in values/strings.xml
<string name="versioned_default_value">Light theme</string>

and in values-v29/strings.xml
<string name="versioned_default_value">Use OS Setting</string>
<string name="non_default_value">Light theme</string>

Comment: Yeah, something like that (though I'm not sure how you're using the `non_default_value`, exactly). Isn't that how you're handling the `entries` and `entryValues`, too? I mean, I'm slightly confused as to what you're asking, because it seems like you've already got the exact behavior you want with those attributes and the `<string-array>`s, and you just need to do the same thing with the `defaultValue` and a `<string>` resource for it. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: What you're suggesting makes sense to me only if the defaultValue
string isn't user-visible (and isn't translated.) I've always had
entries and entryValues be the same array of user-visible strings (which is the unwritten assumption that has us confused, I think. :-) But if the entryValues are different from the entries, not user-visible, and one of them is the defaultValue then I can see how it'd work. I'll try.